# Google Maps Javascript API, how do you draw new markers and center without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[Google Maps Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)

I want to add a button to my page that when clicked the map removes the old markers, adds new markers and centers over the last marker added.

For example, call update() and it posts to server and returns new data for map,

```
function update() {
 $.post( '[website]', { post:'map' }, function(data) { if(data) { ??? }});
}
```

I know there is a way to modify the map by adding internal controls onto the map, but is there a way to basicaly create a new map with new data without reloading the page?

Comment: Nope! (until now for my knowledge.. but working on it!), you have to set a marker for each values on map load. To display it or not is another thing... Wich is allowing a user interface to filter it. A super great example in which I contributed [is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mcvozo6l74Tlyk4aTovg?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Found it, [Listening to DOM events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener)

```
function initMap() {
 var myExternalButton = document.getElementById('myExternalButton');
 var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
  zoom: 8,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
 });
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(myExternalButton, 'click', function() {
  window.alert('External button was clicked!');
 });
}
```